# How to categorize files from Amazon S3 ls command?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

To make a list of file names in an Amazon S3 bucket using the following (in Python):

```
import os
os.system('aws s3 ls s3://bucket --recursive --human-readable --summarize')
```

The output is:

```
2021-10-02 21:37:53   10 MiB img.txt
2021-10-02 21:37:53   10 MiB img.jpg
2021-10-02 21:32:57   10 MiB img.json
2021-10-02 21:32:58   10 MiB img.png

Total Objects: 4
Total Size: 40 MiB
```

The desirable output should be:

```
Total Objects: 4
Total Size: 40 MiB
.jpg count: 1
.png count 1
.json count 1
.txt count 1
```

and Total Size is a variable that could be used later in that program.

Comment: I don't get why you're using the AWS CLI for this. Python has the `boto3` library which can make this same task much easier.

Comment: actually I want the full size of the file without downloading that. And want to get the count of all elements. If it is possible using boto3. Then pls help me out.

Comment: I would recommend checking out the boto3 docs. There's a good page with some [example codes](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-examples.html) that you could probably start with.

Comment: In this case, the [list_objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects) call is probably what you want to check out. This can be used to list all objects in a bucket, and get the size of each object.

Comment: want to access EC2 machine.

import os
os.system(‘ssh xxxxxxxxxxx.pem ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xx’)

Upto the 2nd line its going correctly. But I want to access the subfolder Documents in EC2 machine. That I cant using os.system(‘cd Documents’).
I want to access this:

ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xx:~/Documents $

Comment: As was recommended below also, I'd also suggest opening a new question for this. This seems unrelated to the initial question on listing objects in the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of doing it with the `boto3` library:

```py
import boto3

extensions = {}
object_count = 0
total_size = 0

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

for object in s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket').objects.all():
    key = object.key
    object_count += 1
    total_size += object.size

    ext = key[key.rfind('.'):]
    extensions[ext] = extensions.get(ext, 0) + 1

print('Total Objects:', object_count)
print('Total size (MiB):', total_size // 1024 // 1024)
for ext in extensions:
    print(ext, extensions[ext])
```

Comment: want to access EC2 machine.
      
import os        
os.system(‘ssh xxxxxxxxxxx.pem ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xx’)

Upto the 2nd line its going correctly. But I want to access the subfolder Documents in EC2 machine. That I cant using       os.system(‘cd Documents’).
I want to access this:

ubuntu@xx.xxx.xx.xx:~/Documents $

Comment: @Codu You appear to be asking about something that is not related to your original question. Please create a new Question rather than asking via a comment on this Question. I would also recommend against using SSH from code -- there is probably a better way to achieve your _actual_ goal (whatever that is), so when you create your new Question please include details of _what_ you are wanting to achieve rather than _how_ you are attempting to achieve it (eg If you want to copy a file to/from an EC2 instance).

Comment: Sir, I am new in AWS...Please help me out... should I use ......... 'my_bucket' as 'aws s3 ls s3://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/'?

Comment: @Codu I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Are you doing an assignment? Your question is very similar to [python 3.x - How to calculate number of files of a specific extension without download from AWS S3 bucket - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69478177/how-to-calculate-number-of-files-of-a-specific-extension-without-download-from-a).